# How to Create levels in game in libgdx

Tags: android, physics, libgdx, game-design

I am create trying to create a Android game using Libgdx. I want to Create levels in game . So what i do. Which classes i need to use and how to create them explained. Plz help.Also i want to add buttons to game to move a car from left to right. plz tell me

Comment: You could start by learning some basic Java applications to get the hang of it, then move with simple games such as space invaders or even pong, then you might have enough experience to find how to do this fairly broad question on your own

Comment: First, you are asking two unrelated questions. Please only ask one question per post. Second, there are many possible ways to create levels, and there is no "best" one, because that depends on your game, how your software architecture looks and on your personal requirements and preferences. This makes this question impossible to answer in an objective way. Third, this is just my opinion, but when you haven't even got input handling yet, it's still too early to think about asset management. Take one step at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibGDX is not like some simplistic game engines so there is no set way to create levels. It completely depends on your game. If you would create a 2D game with tiles then you can use a simple CSV file where you put in numbers that correspond to your textures or perhaps a image where the pixels correspond to textures. There are some libraries and programs that integrate well with LibGDX but I personally never used them much.

- [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/), LibGDX has functionality to load in the maps you create in there.
- [overlay2D](http://overlap2d.com/) You can drag and drop stuff on a canvas and export that to your project. I have no experience with this but it looks great.

I'm not aware of a 3D level builder but imho LibGDX should be used for 2D althought it can deal with 3D pretty good. For 3D there are other engines out there like unity and UE4. But you can always role your own 3D map editor in LibGDX.